# Limited height HTML content preview

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer

I'm trying to understand if there is an efficient way to have a preview of potentially long HTML content.

For example, I have a very long article with markup and tables, with tables sometimes being the very first thing in the article. I want to be able to efficiently render the first 300px (in height), which upon a click I will display in a scrollable dialog.

My current solution was to strip all HTML tags and just render x number of lines in plain text, however this solution is not acceptable as it fails pretty badly on tables.

On a page I might have multiple elements with long html content previews, so I would prefer some other approach than just have CSS restricted height blocks, but with all content rendered by the browser, as I assume this will be quite inefficient.

Comment: What about putting all content to container with fixed height and overflow: hidden? On click you can add overflow-x: auto.

Comment: I'm not sure how browsers would implement this, but if I have multiple previews of very long content, wouldn't all that content be pre-rendered by the browser to show only this small preview?

Comment: Yes, all content would be pre-rendered.

Comment: use lazy loading or infinite scroll, so that only what's visible is rendered

Comment: Pretty tough question. Can think of two solutions at the moment. 1. On the server use a headless browser to prerender the page and determine how much 300px is displaying. Or 2. load the content a string; Have an empty container and add top level nodes from the content string in a loop. After each step check the used height and stop when 300px+ is reached.